# Property of Weighted Projection onto Spectral Norm Ball

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are rectangular matrices of the same size with more rows than columns, and that all singular values of $\mathbf{A}$ are greater than $c$.  Let $\mathbf{L}$ be a lower-triangular matrix with positive elements on the diagonal.

Consider the optimization problem
$$ \hat{\mathbf{X}} = \text{arg}\min_{\mathbf{X}} || (\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{A}) \mathbf{L}  ||^2_F  \quad \text{subject to} \quad ||\mathbf{X}||_2 \le c $$
where $||\cdot||_2$ denotes the spectral norm of a matrix.

I'm trying to prove that *all* singular values of the optimal solution $\hat{\mathbf{X}}$ are *exactly equal* to $c$.  By the constraint, we know that none of the singular values can be strictly greater than $c$, so I just need to prove that none can be strictly less than $c$ either.

I imagine that one way forward is to prove that any $\mathbf{X}$ with a singular value strictly less than $c$ must *not* be the optimal solution because one can modify it somehow to produce a better solution.

Another proof strategy would be to show that if $\hat{\mathbf{X}}$ has a singular value strictly less than $c$, then $\mathbf{A}$ has a singular value strictly less than $c$.

Answer (score 1):

We consider the function $f:X\in B_c\rightarrow tr((X-A)LL^T(X^T-A^T))$, where $B_c$ is the ball of radius $c$ for $||.||_2$. Note that $B_c$ is compact convex and $f$ is convex. Then $\min(f)$ is reached in a unique point of the boundary $F$ of $B_c$. Unfortunately $F$ is very complicated. Indeed, a matrix in $F$ may have only one singular value equal to $c$...

When $n=2$, it is true that $\min(f)$ is reached for a matrix s.t. $X^TX=c^2I_2$; yet, the case $n>2$ seems to be more difficult.